# How to make data insertion, modification, deletion, and search by pressing the j button in the jdbc program?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I tried to implement an event when the button is pressed by attaching an action listener to the insert, edit, delete, and search buttons.
It seems that the data in the database is not properly inserted, modified, deleted, or searched because of the wrong data manipulation language.
And I want to output the result of manipulating the database data in JTextArea.
How to modify the source code?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MovieManagement extends JFrame {
    Container c = this.getContentPane();

    public teamMovie2() {
        this.setSize(500, 400);
        this.setTitle("movie");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setDesign();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

// gui
    private void setDesign() {
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel pTop = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        // p1
        JLabel title = new JLabel("title");
        JTextField title_tf = new JTextField(20);
        p1.add(title);
        p1.add(title_tf);
        // p2
        JLabel director = new JLabel("director");
        JTextField director_tf = new JTextField(20);

        JLabel genre = new JLabel("genre");
        String[] combGName = { "all", "action", "comedy", "drama", "melo", "horror/thriller", "SF/fantasy", "animation" };
        JComboBox<String> combG = new JComboBox<String>(combGName);

        JLabel time = new JLabel("time");
        String[] combTName = {"all", "within 1hour", "within an hour and a half", "within 2hours", "within two and a half hours"};
        JComboBox<String> combT = new JComboBox<String>(combTName);

        JLabel mainActor = new JLabel("mainActor");
        JTextField mainActor_tf = new JTextField(20);

        JLabel rating = new JLabel("rating");
        String[] combRName = { "all", "r12", "r15", "r18" };
        JComboBox<String> combR = new JComboBox<String>(combRName);

        JLabel country = new JLabel("country");
        String[] combCName = { "all", "america", "asia", "west" };
        JComboBox<String> combC = new JComboBox<String>(combCName);

        p2.add(director);
        p2.add(director_tf);
        p2.add(genre);
        p2.add(combG);
        p2.add(time);
        p2.add(combT);
        p2.add(mainActor);
        p2.add(mainActor_tf);
        p2.add(rating);
        p2.add(combR);
        p2.add(country);
        p2.add(combC);
        // p3
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("insert");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("update");
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("delete");
        p3.add(btn1);
        p3.add(btn2);
        p3.add(btn3);
        // p4
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        ta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
        p4.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
        // p5
        JButton seb = new JButton("search");
        p5.add(seb);
        // add panel to contentpane
        pTop.add(p1);
        pTop.add(p2);
        pTop.add(p3);
        c.add(pTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(p4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(p5, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // data insert
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton btn1  = (JButton)e.getSource();
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/movie_db?serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul","root","1234");
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO management VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                 catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // data update
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton btn2  = (JButton)e.getSource();
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/movie_db?serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul","root","1234");
                    String sql = "UPDATE management SET WHERE";
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                 catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        // data delete
                btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JButton btn3  = (JButton)e.getSource();
                        try {
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/movie_db?serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul","root","1234");
                            String sql = "DELETE FROM management WHERE";
                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                            ps.executeUpdate();
                        }
                         catch (ClassNotFoundException e3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e3.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SQLException e3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e3.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                
                // data search
                btn4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JButton btn4  = (JButton)e.getSource();
                        try {
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/movie_db?serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul","root","1234");
                            String sql = "SELECT * FROM management";
                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                            ps.executeUpdate();
                        }
                         catch (ClassNotFoundException e4) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e4.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SQLException e4) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e4.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    // VO 
    class MovieModel {
        String title; 
        String director; 
        String mainActor; 
        String[] genre = {  "all", "action", "comedy", "drama", "melo", "horror/thriller", "SF/fantasy", "animation" }; // genre
        String[] time = {"all", "within 1hour", "within an hour and a half", "within 2hours", "within two and a half hours" }; // running time
        String[] rating = {  "all", "r12", "r15", "r18" }; // firm rating
        String[] country = { "all", "america", "asia", "west" }; // country

        MovieModel(String title, String director, String[] genre, String[] time, String main_actor, String[] rating,
                String[] country) {
            this.title = title;
            this.director = director;
            this.genre = genre;
            this.time = time;
            this.mainActor = main_actor;
            this.rating = rating;
            this.country = country;

        }

        public class MovieDAO {
            
            Connection con = null;
            
            Statement stmt = null;
            
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            
            ResultSet rs = null;

            // DB connect 
            public Connection makeConnection() {
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/movie_db?serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul";
                String id = "root";
                String password = "1234";
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    System.out.println("drive loading success");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, password);
                    System.out.println("Database connection successful");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Driver not found");
                    e.getStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Connection failed");
                    System.out.println("SQLEXception" + e.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("SQLState" + e.getSQLState());
                    System.out.println("VendorError" + e.getErrorCode());
                }
                return con;
            }

            /* DB close */
            public void disConnection() {
                try {
                    if (rs != null)
                        rs.close();
                    if (stmt != null)
                        stmt.close();
                    if (ps != null)
                        ps.close();
                    if (con != null)
                        con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }
    }

    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MovieManagement();
    }
}
```

I googled mysql data manipulation language.

Comment: Why do you think your ps will do an update for a select `String sql = "SELECT * FROM management";` ?  Have a look at the javadocs.

Comment: I wanted to be able to retrieve all the data in the table.

Comment: Should I modify the sql statement?

Comment: Yes and no.  But more importantly I think that you should follow a jdbc tutorial.  For example when doing an INSERT you need to provide that data that you want inserted.  When doing a delete your sql is incorrect.  When doing a select you are using the wrong java method.  So much is wrong.

Comment: oh my mistake
I'm pretty sure I need to provide data to insert data.
And when I provide data, I think I have to do something like ps.setString = ps(1, attribute), but what is the best way to do it in this source code?

Comment: If I want to delete each attribute, how should I write the sql statement?

Comment: The basic form of the sql statement's deletion method is "DELETE [FROM] table name
I know it's a WHERE condition", but I'm asking again if I want to make each attribute deleteable.

Comment: I'm really sorry if it looks hasty.

Comment: *I want to make each attribute deleteable.* - I have no idea what you mean.  Rows from a table are deleted.

Comment: oh,I see.....I was trying to ask how to make each column in the table be deleted.

Comment: why would you want to do this?  Table manipulation is not something that is generally done using java.  Use the mysql client program.

Comment: I see.. I want the basic table to appear on the gui screen, and when data is manipulated, the result is displayed on the gui screen.
Can data manipulation results be displayed in the gui with only sql statements and not java?

Comment: Looks to me like a duplicate of this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/74362785/131872. The answer in that question was that your SQL statement does nothing because you don't pass any data to the PreparedStatement. Same comment here.